mvn doesn't download dependent module, resulting in either compile or test errors
Our team maintains the "platform" used by a large number of SpringBoot services built with Maven.  We provide a number of library artifacts that are used explicitly or implicitly by these services.  We are in the midst of upgrading the entire platform from Java11/SpringBoot2.x to Java17/SpringBoot3.x.  We are using Maven v3.9.6.
Some of those libraries are composed of multiple modules, in a multimodule Maven build (which I've realized is completely pointless, which I will rip out after our next release).  For instance, one library has two modules that I'll call "web" and "core".  The pom.xml for the "web" module specifies the "core" module as a dependency, although curiously specifies the "scope" property explicitly as "compile" (that's the default).
I can see both artifacts in our intranet artifact repository.
We have a parent pom that specifies the "web" artifact as a dependency.
If I do a local build of a service, it is now failing, complaining about missing classes that reside in the "core" artifact.  I looked in my local maven repo, and only the "web" artifact was present. The "core" artifact was not there.
I then performed a checkout of the code for that library, and did a "mvn install", and then I looked in my local maven repo.  Both "web" and "core" were present. Running the build of the service now succeeds.
For some reason, mvn initiated the download of the "web" artifact, but for some reason made no attempt to download the "core" artifact, which is clearly a dependency of the "web" artifact.
One odd thing I noticed, which again shouldn't make any difference, is that explicit "scope" value of "compile" in the "web" pom.xml, for the "core" artifact. I can't believe that would make any difference, but it is odd looking.
Update:
I've managed to resolve this.  I'll provide more details of the structure, but there's something about this that I still don't fully understand.
Our services reference a parent pom, which specifies a BOM as a dependency with import scope, and the parent pom also has a "sdk" artifact that includes as dependencies all the artifacts that most services need, all of which have versions defined in the BOM.
For all of the libraries that are module-based, the BOM and the sdk artifact all specify as dependencies all the modules for each library. However, we missed one.  For this particular library that has the "web" and "core" modules, the BOM and the sdk only specified the "web" artifact.  I verified that after adding that missing dependency to the BOM and the sdk pom, and installing those locally, and then deleting the "web" and "core" artifacts from my local maven repo, and then rerunning the build of the service, it completes successfully, and I now see both the "web" and "core" artifacts in the local maven repo.
So, problem solved.  However, here's the part that confuses me.  In the pom for the "web" artifact, it specifies the "core" library as a dependency.  The "web" artifact had always been specified as a dependency in the sdk artifact, and had its version specified in the BOM.  Although I can clearly see now that I have to explicitly specify both "web" and "core" in the sdk, I don't understand why maven wasn't downloading the "core" artifact to the local maven repo when it downloaded the "web" artifact, because it clearly specifies "core" as a dependency.

are those modules/projects are organised locally in the way that parent.relativePath points to the existing pom file of parent project?

which I've realized is completely pointless, which I will rip out after our next release if one module is a spring boot application and the other "only" lib called "core" there is a good thing because you can not use a spring boot app as a dependency... the other question is: If things only work after doing mvn install there are other things wrong... but without a concrete example it's hard to tell or even guess...

The library with modules is a root project directory, with the two modules as subdirectories, we're not setting relativePath.

The only place we have modules is in libraries, not springboot applications.

I've managed to resolve this, which I'll describe as an update to the main post, but there's an aspect of this that I've never fully understood.
